# Adding a continuous color gradient legend strip to plot

Tags: r, plot

I am using following data and code to plot a `barplot`:

```
ddf=structure(list(VAR = structure(1:9, .Label = c("aaa", "bbb", 
"ccc", "ddd", "eee", "fff", "ggg", "hhh", "iii"), class = "factor"), 
    VAL = c(0L, 32L, 64L, 96L, 128L, 160L, 192L, 224L, 256L)), .Names = c("VAR", 
"VAL"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))

barplot(ddf$VAL,col=rgb(ddf$VAL,256-ddf$VAL,0,maxColorValue=256))
```

How can I add a legend strip having these colors on it, with corresponding values written there? I want a legend strip as appears in following plot:

```
library(latticeExtra)
dat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1000), y = rnorm(1000), z = rnorm(1000, mean = 1))
maxz <- max(abs(dat$z))
levelplot(z ~ x * y, dat, at = seq(-maxz, maxz, length = 100), panel = panel.levelplot.points, par.settings = custom.theme.2())
```

I have tried to use following function examples but am unable to modify them to my needs:

```
legend("bottom", legend = LETTERS[1:6], col = c6, ncol = 2, cex = 2, lwd = 3, text.font = i, text.col = c6)

libarary(plotrix)
testcol<-color.gradient(c(0,1),0,c(1,0),nslices=5)
color.legend(11,6,11.8,9,col.labels,testcol,gradient="y")
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The trick is to draw the color key as an image in a separate panel. Notice that I decrese the margin between the panels by reducing `par(mar=...)` and add an outer margin around both panels with `par(oma=...)`.

```
my.palette <- rgb(ddf$VAL,256-ddf$VAL,0,maxColorValue=256)

# Create two panels side by side
layout(t(1:2), widths=c(5,1))

# Set margins and turn all axis labels horizontally (with `las=1`)
par(mar=rep(.5, 4), oma=rep(3, 4), las=1)

barplot(ddf$VAL,col=my.palette)

# Draw the color legend
image(1, ddf$VAL, t(seq_along(ddf$VAL)), col=my.palette, axes=FALSE)
axis(4)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for something like this only. Can we make it little smaller in both width and height?

Comment: I could reduce the width with widths=c(5,0.5)) but how to reduce the height?

Comment: To make it shorter you can add some more margin with `par(mar=c(4,1,4,1)` just before the call to `image`.

Comment: Yes it works. Thanks. I had expected a solution using legend or color.legend function.

Answer (score 3):

just for completeness the color.legend version, because I think it's the easiest one:

your data:

```
ddf=structure(list(VAR = structure(1:9, .Label = c("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee", "fff", "ggg", "hhh", "iii"), class = "factor"),                       VAL = c(0L, 32L, 64L, 96L, 128L, 160L, 192L, 224L, 256L)), .Names = ("VAR","VAL"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

now we plot the barplot with the legend.
The numbers are the legend margins (x1,y1,x2,y2)

```
par(mar=c(1,3,1,5)+0.1,xpd=TRUE)
col.pal<-rgb(ddf$VAL,256-ddf$VAL,0,maxColorValue=256)
barplot(ddf$VAL,col=rgb(ddf$VAL,256-ddf$VAL,0,maxColorValue=256))
color.legend(12,220,13,80,rev(ddf$VAL),rev(col.pal),gradient="y")
```

[image: your colorful barplot]

Comment: is this from the `plotrix` package?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use `colors.scale` from the plotrix package and add it for example to the standard `legend`. It's exactly what the `plotZCol` function does in (my) [spatDataManagement](https://bitbucket.org/cmbce/r-package-spatdatamanagement) package.

From the examples :

```
x <- rnorm(1000)
y <- rnorm(1000)
library("spatDataManagement")

plotZCol(x,y,zCol=x+y)
```

[image]