# R: adding a continuous color legend to plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, plotly, data-visualization

I am working with the R programming language. I simulated some data and made the following plot:

```
a = rnorm(1000,10,10)
b = rnorm(1000,10,10)
c = rnorm(1000,10, 1)

d = data.frame(a,b,c)

plot(x = d$a, y = d$b, col = d$c)
```

[image]

In the above plot, the points are colored according to the value of "c". Is it possible to add a legend that shows which colors are associated with which values of "c"?

I know how how to do this using the plotly library:

```
library(plotly)
 plot_ly(data = d, type = "scatter", mode = "markers", x = ~a, y = ~ b, color = ~ c)
```

But is it possible to make this "color gradient legend" using base R?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Note: this color scale is automatically added when I use the ggplot2 library: 
ggplot(d, aes(x=a, y=b, color=c)) +
    geom_point()

Comment: Potential duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13355440/6851825 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/24221547/6851825